# Check if event target is hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I have a large div inside there which are smaller divs, achor tags and other elements.
Each large div in my program is bound to "mousedown" event and inside the onMouseDown handler, I basically check the event.target.

If a user clicks on an items that is a hyper link, I want to check if event.target was hyperlink and then navigate to that link if event.target was a hyperlink. How can that be done?

Here's the structure of the divsa and elements.

```
<div class="camp-name">
    <span class="btnCampaign"><div class=""></div></span>
    <span class="campaign-name">
       <a href="http://www.google.com">Some Link here</a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="campaign-name-sub">
   <span class="campaign-accountname">Some Text here</span>
   <span class="seprator">|</span>
   <span class="brandname">Some Text here</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
var label = label.createElement("DIV");
label.innerHMTL = src //src is the above html that is seen here
    Plugin.addEventListener(label, "mousedown", params.onMouseDown);


Plugin.onMouseDown() = function(event) {
var target = (event.currentTarget) ? event.currentTarget : event.srcElement;
        if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a" && target !== undefined) {
            console.log(target.href);
            Plugin.stopPropagation(event);
        }
};
```

Comment: can you put out some code....like how your divs are organized and stuff

Comment: @theshadowmonkey :  Added. When I click on <a> tag, I still get the event.target as DIV only. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I think the event is getting handled by the parent DIV. Try console.log(event) in Chrome preferably and you should see all parametrs that you can manipulate. I think that should help in some direction

Comment: can you post the exact javascript you are using...I will write a fiddle and try on it

Comment: @theshadowmonkey : The problem here is that I want to write unobstrive javascript wihout using specific id/class if writing something like `find()` (probably looking for a tag is still fine in the sense that if `a` is there, then navigate to it) If I click on an element that is other than the `a` tag, then I don't want to navigate to that `a` tag link. Instead do seomthing from that `mouseDown` event that I already have

Comment: I remodified the code and updated it below...have a look

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You should get it through

```
if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a')
{
    event.target.href; //this is the url where the anchor tag points to.
}
```

Comment: and compare it to what? (I know, but you should include it for a complete answer.)

Comment: That means if (event.target.tagname === 'a') {window.location.href = event.target} . How's this written correctly in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you also piint out how the value inside that event.target I fetched? Is it event.target.valueOf() ?

Comment: @ParthikGosar : Thanks! But I checked and found that @theshadownmonkey was asking for the correct info. When I click on that `<a> </a>` tag, I still get the event.target as DIV. Is there a way out? I have added the `element strcutre` in the above post (easily without jquery since I have built the whole thing in plain and won't want to write jQuery code into it).

Answer (score 22):

You could check the `tagName` property, as said by @parthik-gosar.
Another way is to use the `instanceof` operator to check the element class (hyperlinks are of type `HTMLAnchorElement`):

```
if (event.target instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) {
  console.log(event.target.href);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried modifying your code and there were multiple problems with the code and corrected them.

This is the JavaScript part

```
var src = '<div class="camp-name"><span class="btnCampaign"><div class=""></div></span><span class="campaign-name"><a href="http://www.google.com">Some Link here</a></span></div>';

var label = document.createElement('DIV')
label.innerHTML = src;
var topdiv = document.getElementById("test");
console.log(label)
topdiv.appendChild(label);

label.addEventListener('click', test, false);

function test(event) {
    if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
        var href = event.target.href;
        console.log(href);
    }
    window.location = href;
};
```

This is the HTML part of it

```
<div id="test">
 test
</div>
```

I did this in a jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/KDejm/1/

Please let me know if the vent is captured correctly.

Comment: The problem here is that I want to write unobstrive javascript wihout using specific id/class if writing something like find() (probably looking for a tag is still fine in the sense that if `a` is there, then navigate to it) If I click on an element that is other than the a tag, then I don't want to navigate to that a tag link. Instead do seomthing from that mouseDown event that I already have

Comment: In my javascript, I have a bigger div and as I wrote in my post, that bigger div is getting the HTMl from somewhere and displaying it by `.innerHTML`. That bigger div is the one that has the `mousedown` event bound and I am not allowed to change that particular code. So, in essence, I was looking for a way through which I can check if event.target has an anchor tag (If it has, then navigate) Also, no jQuery allowed for now because of the prior coding style.

Comment: @user1240679 updated the fiddle and answer to reflect your changes