# close modal on click on body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just need to have a modal close on click off of it. I tried 2 approaches:

1. Targeting a click event on `body` and check if the modal has a class and if it does show it
2. check the `event.target` and if it's not the modal hide it

Two attempts are below:

```js
$(function(e) {

  $("#filter-button").click(function(e) {
    $(".dialog").toggleClass("show");
  });

  $("body").click(function() {
    if ($(".dialog").hasClass("show")) {
      $(".dialog").removeClass("show");
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.dialog {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="filter-button">SHOW/HIDE</button>

<div class="dialog"></div>
```

Upon click on "SHOW/HIDE" the modal (a red box) does not even open. I *think* this might have something to do with `#filter-button` being counted as a target? As a troubleshooting initiative for the above sample, I attempted to use `e.currentTarget` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget so basically changing the above to:

```
$(function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
  ...
```

I got nothing in the console so I can't tell if that's the issue.

I also tried to log `e.target` and got no results in the console as well.

Why is that?

My next attempt:

```js
$(function(e) {

  $("#filter-button").click(function(e) {
    $(".dialog").toggleClass("show");
  });
  
  if(e.currentTarget != $("#filter-button")) {
   $(".dialog").removeClass("show");
  }

});
```

```css
.dialog {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="filter-button">SHOW/HIDE</button>

<div class="dialog"></div>
```

The toggle function is restored, but clicking off of the modal does not close it. I found: [Check if event target is hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661343/check-if-event-target-is-hyperlink) so I changed my code to:

```
$(function(e) {

  $("#filter-button").click(function(e) {
    $(".dialog").toggleClass("show");
  });

  if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'body') {
    $(".dialog").removeClass("show");
  }

});
```

This breaks my previous code again, and now my dialog doesn't open at all.

1. howcome I can't console log e.target?
2. Why is the modal not opening at all in the first example? Is it because of a logic error with targeting `body` somehow?
3. Which is the better way? e.target or attaching a click event to the body?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things you could wrap your modal dialogue within a container that is full width and height of the viewport. This way you can show or hide the parent container if it is clicked instead of showing and hiding just the dialogue.

This also allows you to add an overlay with css later on to increase the visibility of the modal.

```js
$(function(e) {

  var modal = $(".modal-wrapper")
  $("#filter-button").click(function(e) {
    modal.toggleClass("show");
  });
  $(window).click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == modal[0]) {
      modal.removeClass("show");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-wrapper {
  display: none;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.modal {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="filter-button">SHOW/HIDE</button>
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div class="modal"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but howcome in my example e.target returns nothing? My example is very close to yours so I don't understand the disconnect

Comment: The main difference in your example is that you are trying to access "e.target" in a conditional where no event is fired rather then accessing it in an event listener. "e.target" as mentioned in Mozilla Docs is, "A reference to the object that dispatched the event." So by binding an object to a click event and passing the event to that handler it is now within context of the clicked object.