# keep modal open despite clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a toggling modal to stay open even when it's clicked on. It has multiple elements inside of it as well, and if one of those is clicked it still needs to stay open. I asked a similar question about click events and event.target: [close modal on click on body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50728455/close-modal-on-click-on-body) and this is a build off of that.

I figured out the previous question, which leaves me with this:

```js
$(function(e) {

  $("#filter-button").click(function(e) {
    $(".dialog").toggleClass("show");
  });

  $(window).click(function(e) {
    if((e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'button') && ($(".dialog").hasClass("show"))) {
     $(".dialog").removeClass("show");
   } else if (e.target.className.toLowerCase() == 'dialog') {
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.dialog {
  display: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="filter-button">SHOW/HIDE</button>

<div class="dialog">
  <h1>Hi</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To explain what I'm trying to do - if the event target in the first if in the window click event is not the button and the dialog is showing, then remove it (expected functionality) - I now need to keep it open if it's clicked inside.

My attempt is this piece:

```
...
else if (e.target.className.toLowerCase() == 'dialog') {
      return false;
    }
...
```

What I thought was going to happen is that if the div is clicked, it will `return: false;` and stay open, preventing the dialog from closing. But it closes anyway. I also need to somehow target all the elements inside of it.

I'm not sure at this point how to move forward? Do I need to include all elements inside the dialog somehow?

Comment: why do you need   $(window).click() ?

Comment: @karthick As I understand it, it is needed in this instance because if I bind the click event to just the button, I can't see what else has been clicked. Part of the feature is to be able to click outside of the modal and close it. But when it's clicked inside it needs to stay open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the event from bubbling up to the parent element (which will close the modal, as expected). You can do that with the following code:

```
$('.dialog').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: This works great! But I don't understand why, because `.dialog` has no parents? Where is it bubbling to? What is causing the bubbling to close the modal?

Comment: It's bubbling to `window` (the element you added the event listener to), which passes your if conditional and thus removes the `show` class and hides the element.

Comment: I think it's considered best practice to include a wrapper element around your modal like this

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="modal"></div>
    </div>

That way you can add an event handler to wrapper that closes any time the wrapper is clicked on (to exit out of the modal) and an event handler on modal that stops propagations (so you can click anywhere on the modal)

Right now you have a click handler on window which is going to fire every single time you click anywhere on the page - not a good thing.

Comment: Jun I agree however the requirement is that elements need to be clickable with the dialog open.